# Can I increase text size within AutoCAD Civil 3D?

Tags: text, civil3d

I have some vision problems and I'm hoping there are options within Civil 3D to increase text size. Glasses will not help, for the record.
I have increased the text size to the maximum limit within Windows before it will disrupt the functionality of the ribbon and sub-menus from functioning properly.
To be clear, the Windows settings have worked on my ribbon and prospector areas, however, when I open dialog boxes, the text is very small again in these Windows. Ie: building a surface or performing a cut/fill analysis. Once I'm into one of these processes, the text is half the font size. Can this be addressed with Civil 3D?

Comment: Do you have a 4K monitor? What year Civil 3D do you have?

Comment: Not sure on the monitors.  I'm at a new job. I have 2020.

Comment: Right-click the C3D icon, then Properties >> Compatability >> Change high DPI settings >> Override high DPI scaling behavior >> System. I had to do this for Autodesk ReCap, and it worked, but when I tried it for Civil 3D I got a fuzzy display. So I live with smaller text in the dialogue boxes.  One thing to try is Windows Magnifier. To quickly turn on Magnifier, press the Windows logo key + Plus sign (+) . To turn off Magnifier, press the Windows logo key + Esc.  I have vision problems too, so I use a 55" 4K TeeVee as my monitor.

Comment: @Pointdump - Thank you.  The CAD settings only fixed certain aspects, however, the magnifier will more than do the job when I can't see something.  Can you post this as an answer and I'll select it as the solution so you get the reputation points.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows Magnifier. To quickly turn on Magnifier, press the Windows logo key + Plus sign (+) . To turn off Magnifier, press the Windows logo key + Esc.

Comment: Tanks again!  Very much appreciated